# how to force kill YARN applicaton in NEW_SAVING State?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have been kill yarn application using command `yarn application -kill <app_id>`.
I submitted a job which is currently under NEW_SAVING state and I want to kill it.

When i try yarn application -kill  i get below message continuously

```
INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Waiting for application application_XXXX_XXXX to be killed.
```

Any idea how can i kill it forcefully?

Answer (score 1):

The output of the 'yarn application -list' contains the following information of yarn applications:

- Application-Id
- Application-Name
- Application-Type
- User
- Queue
- State
- Final-State
- Progress
- Tracking-URL

You can list the applications and awk by the required parameter. For ex: to list the applications by 'Application-Name'

yarn application -list | awk '$6 == "NEW_SAVING" { print $1 }' > applications_list.txt

Then you can iterate through the file and kill the applications as below:

`while read p; do
  echo $p
  yarn application -kill $p
done <applications_list.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to YARN Cluster UI? You could kill the application from UI. Usually, that works better for me than `yarn application -kill`.

[image]